# Cannot change resolution with Xrandr

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, xrandr

  **First Things First**
1. I have looked at dozens of questions and none of them answer mine, nor are they the same case. Most of them are people who don't know how to use Xrandr.
2. *I know how to use Xrandr*. I have written scripts to automatically assign resolutions and configurations at startup. Apparently, what I don't know enough about is Gnome and the GDM.
3. The optimal resolution for my laptop display is 1200x800.
4. When I log in to the Gnome D/E, my resolution is set automatically to 1280x800, which causes the bottom of the screen to go below the bottom of the physical display.
5. I know, beyond the shadow of a doubt, that this is an issue specifically related to the Gnome D/E. I have used several Linux distros as well as Windows and even a couple of Android x86 based OSs and none of them had this problem. In fact, I never had to set the resolution of my main display until using Gnome.

Once I create and set the resolution for LVDS1 (my laptop display), it stays at the resolution that the Gnome d/e (incorrectly) set it to. I am forced to open Displays and choose the resolution which was created in my script.

While this is a workaround, I really don't want to have to go into my display settings every single time I boot my machine into Ubuntu. I would like to keep using Gnome - I like it, but this is a particularly annoying problem.

Please, only helpful feedback. Thank you.